# why axios return promise error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, function, promise, axios, request-promise

i got error every time i click button on sign-in

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

, but after reload error gone. can i know what happened? here's my code on login

```
onSignIn(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    this.Auth.login(this.state.signInUsername, this.state.signInPassword)
      .then(res => {
        this.props.history.replace('/')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err)
      })
  }
```

and this is my auth code:

```
login(username, password){
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', {
      username,
      password
    })
    .then(this._checkStatus)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.data.success === true){
        const payload = {
          name: username,
        }
        this.setToken(payload)
        return Promise.resolve(res)
      }else{
        console.log(res.data.message)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: `.catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    })` is superfluous, drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return axios from login function.

```
login(username, password){
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', {
      username,
      password
    })
    .then(this._checkStatus)
    .then(res => {
      if(res.data.success === true){
        const payload = {
          name: username,
        }
        this.setToken(payload)
        return res;
      }else{
        console.log(res.data.message)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    })
  }
```

Comment: after i used your code, this action not working  this.props.history.replace('/')

Comment: still cannot, i have to reload the page then can redirect

Comment: i used window.location.href = '/' and working, but dunno if this the best way anot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have -two- ".then" for your axios.post.The example provided at axios site uses

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

just one .then  per axios call.